# Showing error page if extension is not writed

Tags: asp.net, routes, custom-error-pages

I'm using Routing module (in Global.asax) with my web application.
I'm writing config likes this;

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Error">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="Error" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="Error" />
</customErrors>
```

**Note :** Error = Error.aspx

If I want to open nonexistent pages, application redirects my Error.aspx

But if Im not using extension in url (Ex; *.aspx, *.html) application redirects default error page.

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

How i fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to use extension of file for redirecting?

Comment: No. If i use extension application using true errorpage but if dont use extension application open default system error page (not mine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle url's without an extension you'll need to create `<httpErrors>` inside you web.config file. This can be achieved as:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" >
<remove statusCode="403"/>
<remove statusCode="404"/>
<remove statusCode="500"/>
<error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="PathTo403ErrorPage" />
<error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="PathTo404ErrorPage" />
<error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="PathTo500ErrorPage" />
</httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Its working without extensions and I'm using customErrors with extensions.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! Good luck with your project